# pmd:NullAssignment not valid for methods?

Tags: java, pmd

There is no assignment in the below code example. I think that this rule should not apply to this code.

[image: problem illustration]

My setup:

- SonarQube 4.5.4 LTS
- PMD plugin 2.3

Comment: The question is not very clear. However, see i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128409/java-is-it-ok-to-set-integer-null for opinions on that matter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
The question whether the code is in fact an assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that this is a known issue: http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/901/